# Difference between estimates from SAS Proc Genmod and Raw averages

Tags: sas

I am trying to find average change in score for a survey response from pre to post at different levels of aggregation using two different methods. In method 1 called the "Raw Method", I calculate the average of pre scores and average of post scores and then take the difference. In method 2 " Genmod Method", I use pre and post as a categorical variable and get the estimate of the interaction term (stage2*rso). Why does not the estimate from method 2 match the average change in scores in method 1? The dataset has multiple pre's and posts for each patient (empi). This probably a very simple problem but I need some understanding. Heres my dataset and code:

```
  empi  Provider    RSO SCORE   STAGE
  1001  A   X   16.5    PRE
  1001  A   X   22.2    POST
  1001  A   X   14.3    PRE
  1001  A   X   23.4    POST
  111   A   X   25.6    PRE
  1002  B   X   32.3    PRE
  1002  B   X   12  POST
  1001  A   X   24.3    PRE
  1002  B   X   15.6    PRE
  1002  B   X   23.7    POST
  112   A   X   10.2    PRE
  1234  C   Y   13.5    PRE
  1234  C   Y   34.2    POST
  1234  C   Y   12.3    PRE

  /** Method 1 **/
  PROC SQL; 
  CREATE TABLE RSOSCORES AS 
   SELECT         stage2, 
           RSO, 
           AVG(SCORE) AS AVG 
      FROM TEST1
      GROUP BY stage2, 
             RSO; 
   QUIT; 
  /** Method 2 **/

  proc genmod data=TEST1; 
  class empi rso stage2; 
  model SCORE  =  stage2 rso stage2*rso; 
  repeated subject = empi/ type=un corrw;
  ods output GEEEmpPEst = myGEE_PEs; 
  run;
```

Comment: Is there a reason they *should* match?

Comment: They probably will not match exactly as one uses modelling while the other does not. But my goal is to get the standard errors for the change in scores and hence planned to use genmod. Just want to be sure the interaction estimates are accurately reflecting the average change in score for RSOs

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good site for this question, then.  Is this really a stats question, not a SAS programming question?  In which case perhaps it should be migrated to [stats.se]

Comment: It is both. I will post it on cross validated.

Comment: It should only be in one or the other, not both, to be clear.  If it's mostly a statistics question, there; if it's mostly "how do I do X in SAS" it's here.

Comment: If I wanted to calculate the standard error of the average change scores how would I do it in SAS? Is Proc Genmod the only method to approach it?